# How to create a numbered and dependent case/subcase environment

Tags: environments, itemize, cases

can we make a numbered and dependent `case`/`subcase` environment. This is much different from what usually a `case` does in Latex. I do not want to use it to break the domain of definition while writing a function, instead it should act like different cases to consider of the parameter while proving something. Much like in `exam` document class, we start `questions` environment and inside that `parts`, `subparts` and so on. Precisely what I want to write is

```
\begin{cases}
 \case
          This is the first case.
\begin{subcases}
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the first case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the first case.
\end{subcases}
\case
          This is the second case.
\begin{subcases}
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the second case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the second case.
\end{subcases}
\end{cases}
```

...and so on. This should produce

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple implementation:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcounter{cases}
\newcounter{subcases}
\newenvironment{mycases}
  {%
    \setcounter{cases}{0}%
    \def\case
      {%
        \par\noindent
        \refstepcounter{cases}%
        \textbf{Case \thecases.}
      }%
  }
  {%
    \par
  }
\newenvironment{subcases}
  {%
    \setcounter{subcases}{0}%
    \def\subcase
      {%
        \par\noindent
        \refstepcounter{subcases}%
        \textit{Subcase (\thesubcases):}
      }%
  }
  {%
  }
\renewcommand*\thecases{\arabic{cases}}
\renewcommand*\thesubcases{\roman{subcases}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mycases}
 \case
          This is the first case.
\begin{subcases}
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the first case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the first case.
\end{subcases}
\case
          This is the second case.
\begin{subcases}
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the second case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the second case.
\end{subcases}
\end{mycases}
\end{document}
```

We could change this a bit to get rid of `subcases`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcounter{cases}
\newcounter{subcases}[cases]
\newenvironment{mycases}
  {%
    \setcounter{cases}{0}%
    \setcounter{subcases}{0}%
    \def\case
      {%
        \par\noindent
        \refstepcounter{cases}%
        \textbf{Case \thecases.}
      }%
    \def\subcase
      {%
        \par\noindent
        \refstepcounter{subcases}%
        \textit{Subcase (\thesubcases):}
      }%
  }
  {%
    \par
  }
\renewcommand*\thecases{\arabic{cases}}
\renewcommand*\thesubcases{\roman{subcases}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mycases}
 \case
          This is the first case.
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the first case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the first case.
\case
          This is the second case.
\subcase
          This is the first subcase of the second case.
\subcase
          This is the second subcase of the second case.
\end{mycases}
\end{document}
```

Both produce:

[image]